# how to fetch a wikipedia geosearch with a correct origin?

Tags: javascript, cors, fetch-api, wikipedia-api

I want to add a "wikipedia-geosearch" feature to my interactive map.
Here is the simplest code for that operation, first attempt:

```js
const buildWikiGeoSearch = (cn, rd, [lon,lat]) =>
    `https://${cn}.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=geosearch&format=json&gsradius=${rd}&gscoord=${lat}|${lon}`;
let query = buildWikiGeoSearch("fr", 2000, [6.94,49.21]);
console.log(`WikiGeoSearch = ${query}`);
const jsonr = fetch(query)
    .then(a => console.log("geoSearch ok") || a.json())
    .then(b => console.log(JSON.stringify(b)))
    .catch(e => console.log("geoSearch crash:", e));
```

It fails, throwing a `TypeError: Failed to fetch` (not really explicit!).

Second attempt, adding `&origin=*`:

```js
const buildWikiGeoSearch = (cn, rd, [lon,lat]) =>
    `https://${cn}.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=geosearch&format=json&gsradius=${rd}&gscoord=${lat}|${lon}`;
let query = buildWikiGeoSearch("fr", 2000, [6.94,49.21]) + "&origin=*"; // ***CHANGE***
const jsonr = fetch(query)
    .then(a => console.log("geoSearch ok") || a.json())
    .then(b => console.log(JSON.stringify(b)))
    .catch(e => console.log("geoSearch crash:", e));
```

It works, but I would like to understand

- what I am doing: what is the exact role of `origin=*`?
- and if I am doing it correctly: is it safe to using `origin=*`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`origin=*` is [a part of the MediaWiki API](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Cross-site_requests#CORS_usage). MediaWiki uses the parameter to return correct Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) headers on its HTTP response, which tells your browser that it's okay for your app to load that data. `origin=*` means that the API should allow *any* origin ("*" stands for [wildcard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_character)).

Using `origin=*` is perfectly fine and safe.

Comment: thanks, I missed that part of the Mediawiki doc. I am always reluctant in using a wildcard, but if you say it's safe, ok.